# SQL Server CE. How to be 100% sure that data is persisted in database file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

We are building client-server application. Client is a WPF application using Entity Framework with SQL Server CE as database. Server is a simple web service.

Client is using SQL Server CE for storing data, however at fixed intervals we are sending data from client to server. We are doing this because client can work totally offline and so as soon as it’s online data are send to server. What we noticed is that when user save some data and transaction is committed data are not immediately in database.

I know it's because of how SQL Server CE works and that data are pushed to database file at certain intervals. It can be changed by setting flush interval = 1, however I think it’s not working as it's supposed to or we are doing something wrong, which of course is possible. Because of that when transaction was committed in one thread and we read database in thread that sends data to server we sometimes(it’s not very often but for us it's totally unacceptable)  get data from SQL Server CE cache.

If that happens and client send data to server and in same moment app crash or user close it we have client and server databases in totally inconsistent state. That behaviour was our mistake because we were not waiting for sending thread to finish on app close and connection wasn't disposed correctly.

However I'm still not confident if that's enough. Is there any way to be 100% sure that all transactions that were committed are really persisted in the SQL Server CE database file?

Comment: what do you guys have in place in regards to `Delta's` when working with `Disconnected RecordSets` perhaps there is a flaw in how you guys are inserting and or updating `Delta's`

Comment: Yes: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/05/sql-server-compact-code-snippet-of-week_21.html

Comment: We use EF, and i don't think it's posible to implement this solution with it.